# Can't find back the procedure to make a bootable key (suggested at first use of the computer)

Tags: dell, live-usb, usb-drive

I'm new to Ubuntu. I ordered a dell machine with Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed. When I turned the machine on for the first time, I had all these first time settings to do and it suggested I create a bootable USB key in case I want to re-install the factory settings at some point. I skipped this step because I had no usb stick with me at that time, but now that I have one I don't find back the procedure/tool to do it. Therefor I am wondering how I can do this now.

Thanks !

Doug

Comment: I think Dell has a customized grub with extra entries. But grub does not normally show when you only have one operating system. If you press escape right after Dell on screen, full cold reboot, do you get grub menu and additional entries? Often recovery is based on another partition on hard drive with the recovery image. But if hard drive fails you want to have a way to totally restore system without that partition (and back that up also). http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Startup Disk Creator` to create a bootable usb stick. It should already be installed, use the search function to start it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-creator.html.en